# Python script - apply only to selected

Tags: python, animation, scripting

[image]

Is there a way to tell the script to only apply the changes (moving keyframes in this case) to selected object(s)?

Here is the specific code I'm trying to modify:

```
for action in bpy.data.actions:
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            point.co.x **=2
```

Comment: To aid people wanting to help it would be better if you could write the code in the question instead of just having an image of it.

Comment: You are right, but i don't thing that my code is really related to the answer - it is just a specific example...

Comment: but here's the code' if its can help anybody to help me -     for action in bpy.data.actions:
        for fcurve in action.fcurves:
            for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
                point.co.x **=2

Comment: Use the [edit] link to add it into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender stores a list of the currently selected objects in `bpy.context.selected_objects`. It's not *always* as easy as this, to only effect the selected objects, but for your example you would access the current action of the selected object with the `animation_data.action` property:

```
import bpy

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    for fcurve in object.animation_data.action.fcurves:

        for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:

            point.co.x **=2
```

Comment: thnx very much!

Comment: Actually, as i haven't been answered **this question** - [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/automate-keyframes-group-to-non-linear-position/61938#61938)  - I'm trying to write my own script... Hope it will help someone.

Comment: The only reason I thought having the code was relevant is that depending on what properties you want to change the code could be far more complex. For example, if you wanted to effect the textures of the selected objects you would have to loop through the object's materials (doing various checks to make sure they exist) and then loop through the material's textures.

Comment: Ok, I see. The problem that's I'm not a programmer but a graphic designer, so I didn't thought to look deeper into the problem... Feeling a need to start learning Python... Thank you very much for help.